# How to stop posting same post title in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am trying to stop posting in admin panel with same title post but i didn't find any plugin. What i find is only gives notification not stopped the user to not to add the post. Is there any changes in the code or is there any plugin which i am not able to find it. Help me with this if something changes in the code of the WordPress and remember that it is in the admin panel of the WordPress.

Here is the screen Shot which i want to stop posting if admin try to add same title.
[seee the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klsvZ.png)

Comment: Anyone have expertise in WordPress

Comment: Whenever you create a post, you always get same title ''Get connected" is that the issue?

Comment: @MrJackMcfreder  see, there is a already post which have name word , When i add a new post and try give it same name word it is publishing the post , What i need is its should not publish the post . Please help me with this, i am struggling for a week

Comment: Anyone is here ................

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `unique title checker` plugin. It will help you to identify which post title is already exists. You can find it [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/unique-title-checker/)

Comment: It only gave the notification when i hit publish it publish the duplicate post.